# React-native-rn tailwind doesn't generate tailwind.json

Tags: reactjs, react-native, tailwind-css

I followed all the steps of installing react-native-rn.

Everything worked fine at first, but when I moved `input.css`to `src/css/input.css`,it just generates `src/css/tailwind.css`, but not the `src/css/tailwind.json` file

I did modify the lines at `package.json` so they look like this.

```json
"build:tailwind": "tailwindcss --input ./src/css/input.css -o ./src/css/tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer && tailwind-rn",

"dev:tailwind": "concurrently \"tailwindcss -i ./src/css/input.css -o ./src/css/tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer --watch\" \"tailwind-rn --watch\""
```

This is basically how my directory looks *(I hided folders as node_modules, android, etc)*

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the end of either command in `package.json` you'll see they both have `tailwind-rn`, basically what the command does is: *take this file (tailwind.css) and compile it to (tailwind.json)*

So, because you changed the path, default values *(`react-native-rn --input tailwind.css --output tailwind.json`)* don't work.

Manually add at the end of the commands `react-native-rn --input path/to/the/generated/css.css --output path/to/where/you/want/your/json.json`

In this example, it this would be:
*-i equals to --input, and -o to --ouput*

```json
"build:tailwind": "tailwindcss --input ./src/css/input.css -o ./src/css/tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer && tailwind-rn -i ./src/css/tailwind.css -o ./src/css/tailwind.json",

"dev:tailwind": "concurrently \"tailwindcss -i ./src/css/input.css -o ./src/css/tailwind.css --no-autoprefixer --watch\" \"tailwind-rn -i ./src/css/tailwind.css -o ./src/css/tailwind.json\""
```

Also remember to edit `App.js` imports

```
//from
import utilities from './tailwind.json';

//to
import utilities from './src/css/tailwind.json';
```