# Tailwind css for React native not working

Tags: react-native, tailwind-css

I am using the below code but there's no effect of tailwind classes in the app. .

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text, View } from 'react-native';
import {useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn';

export default function App() {
  const tailwind = useTailwind();
  return (
    <View style={tailwind("flex-1 justify-center items-center")}>
      <Text>Welcome to React-Native!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Also i would like to clarify i have already done the required operations , but i noticed tailwind.css, and, consequently tailwind.json got both empty. Any help is welcome, thank you.

Comment: Did you  try this? It might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71272641/react-native-rn-tailwind-doesnt-generate-tailwind-json

Answer (score 0):

Use This Import

```
import { TailwindProvider } from 'tailwindcss-react-native'
```

instead of

```
import {useTailwind} from 'tailwind-rn';
```